# ld.exe, final link failed: Permission denied - write access: yes, process still running: no

Tags: ld, ming

I have a strange error. It popped out of nowhere. I was happily building (Eclipse + MingW) and suddenly on one build I got this message

> c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   final link failed: Permission denied

Normally this happens in these two cases:

- no write access on build target
- compiled exe still running invisible

Both cases are false in my case (doubled checked both on every occurance of the error, and I compiled several times before already without problems, without leaving Eclipse).

I can work around it by cleaning the build space (Project->Clean...), but some builds later it starts to happen again.

What other situations can cause this failure? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Process may still be started even if it seems closed. This is easy to check with task manager.

2) Your EXE may be open by another process like some buggy debugger that forgot to close its handles or virus or anti-virus (that is not much different from virus :) ).

Anti-virus's work seem likely.

Comment: Task manager doesn't have it. I run it outside of debugger. The last few build went fine.

Comment: @blubberbernd: What about the rest? Do you have anti-virus?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Security Essentials. But it never made problems before. I use the exact same build system for weks now already.

Comment: @blubberbernd: So may be this is it. Or something else.